# How to use SQL PIVOT to reflect dates as ROWS

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
m.ProjectNum,
m.siteid, d.* 
FROM DWCorp.SSMaster m 
INNER JOIN DWCorp.SSDetail d ON d.MasterId = m.Id WHERE m.ProjectNum = 'OJER00025' and d.ActionId = 7
```

Which returns the following
[image]

I have the following code:

```
select * from
(
SELECT 
m.siteid,
d.CreatedDate,
m.ProjectNum

FROM DWCorp.SSMaster m 
INNER JOIN DWCorp.SSDetail d ON d.MasterId = m.Id WHERE m.ProjectNum = 'OJER00025' and d.ActionId = 7
)as Sourcetable
pivot
(
max(createddate)
for siteid in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) As pivottable
```

Which returns:

[image]

How do I get the dates to appear in the row instead of NULL ?

Comment: It would be a LOT easier to help here if you could provide ddl, sample data and the desired output.

Comment: There's only `siteid` `16` in your screen shot. Are there any records where `siteid` is `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`?

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!